# Mysql joins and concatenate

Tags: mysql, sql, join, concatenation

I have two tables:

```
table_a:            table_b
+----+------+    +----+---------+------+
| id | name |    | id | relation| name | 
+----+------+    ++++++---------+------+
| 1  | bob  |    | 1  | friend  | chris|
| 2  | jim  |    | 1  | friend  | jon  |
| 3  | tom  |    | 1  | brother | matt |
+----+------+    | 2  | friend  | sam  |
                 | 2  | parent  | ron  |
                 +----+---------+------+
```

and I want to enter a query to output something like

```
+----+------+------------+---------+--------+
| id | name |friend      | brother | parent |
+----+------+------------+---------+--------+
| 1  | bob  | chris, john| matt    |        |
| 2  | jim  | sam        |         |  ron   |
+----+------+------------+---------+--------+
```

So the id is the comman variable between the two tables,
the relation variables have preset values (either friend, brother, parent and maybe a couple other types), and there can be multiple table_b.name per relation per id.

Is this too complicated a task to do?

Comment: Just a note: the 'id' is table_b should not be named so, but should use something like table_a_id for readability purpose

Comment: you could use a case statement to achieve this in the select query.

Comment: @Naveen: you don't need to rename the column as the table name/alias will make that clear: table_b.id etc.

Comment: @davek here the table_b.id is not referring to the primary key of table_b. please check. but it is a foreign key of the table_a

Comment: @Naveen: you're quite right - I misread that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID, a.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN relation = 'friend' THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) friend,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN relation = 'brother' THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) brother,
        GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN relation = 'parent' THEN b.name ELSE NULL END) parent
FROM  table_a a
        INNER JOIN table_b b
            ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.ID, a.name
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99c0d/2)

in future, if you have any other relation other than `friend, brother, and parent` and you don't want to alter the query, you can use prepared statement

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN relation = ''',
      relation,
      ''' then b.name ELSE NULL end) AS ',
      relation
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM table_b;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT a.ID, a.name, ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM  table_a a
                         INNER JOIN table_b b
                             ON a.id = b.id
                   GROUP BY a.ID, a.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99c0d/3)

Comment: +1 nice and neat. Just wondering, though: does the presence of one NULL in the group_concat reduce the whole string to a NULL?

Comment: more ref:  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you're right, it was an honest mistake and i found out after i ran on sqlfiddle,

Comment: @davek nope, when using `aggregate function` it drops null value.

Comment: Where you have a.ID, is that table_a.ID? If so on the FROM and INNER JOIN, you have table_a a and table_b b. I'm not sure how that works because there's no table or header called a or b.

Comment: @kojitron they are called `ALIAS`. I used to supply alias on the table to minimize the query (*useful in table with longer names*). so instead of writing `table_a`, you can use `a`.